# ¿como convertir un objeto BufferedImage a un byte[]?

Tags: java

tengo una objeto de tipo `BufferedImage` que estoy llenado con una captura de pantalla usando AWT

`BufferedImage imagexd = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));`

Obtengo la imagen correctamente en el objeto pero ahora quiero almacenarla en la maquina. 
ya conocia como almacenar este tipo de datos con `OutputStream.write` asi

(`OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ruta");
out.write(bytes);`)

el problema es que recibe un arreglo de bytes (byte[]) y buffered image no tiene ningun metodo para obtener esto (al menos por lo que investigue), entonces mi pregunta es como puedo obtener el byte[] de ese BufferedImage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien tampoco tengo idea como obtener el arreglo de `bytes[]` de un `BufferedImage` directamente, hay otra forma que podrias utilizar

1- Primero creas un objeto de tipo `ByteArrayOutputStream` por el cual obtendremos el array mas adelante

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteConte= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

2-Utilizando `ImageIO.write` vas a escribir la imagen sobre el `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
ImageIO.write(imagexd, "jpg" byteConte);
```

Aquie estas pasando el BufferedImage (**imagexd**), el tipo o formato de este (**jpg**), y en donde escribiremos nuestra imagen (**byteConte**)

3-Luego solo es obtener el arreglo directamente del `ByteArrayOutputStream` con `toByteArray()` de esta forma:

```
byte[] bytes = byteConte.toByteArray();
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta theboshy era lo lo que buscaba